# UseEffect not working in child component when reloading

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I have a website with 1 child component and the parent both have useEffect, but when reloading the page, only the parent component's useEffect runs, the child component doesn't. I have used async await but it still doesn't work. Thank you for your answer!

Here 're my code:

- Child component

```
useEffect( () => {
    let q = handleGetQuantityById(Id)
    console.log(q)
  }, [])
```

- Parent component:

```
const getQuantityByID = (Id) => {
    productList.filter((item) => {
      let result = 0;
      if (item.ProductId === Id) {
        result = item.Quantity;
        console.log("Quantity" + result);
        return result;
      }
    });
  };
return (
...
<div>
{_.map(products, (item, i) => {
                // let quantity = getQuantityByID(item.Id);
                return (
                  <QuickBuyProduct
                    data={item}
                    handleGetQuantityById={getQuantityByID}
                    key={i}
                  />
                );
              })}
</div>
...
)
```

Comment: Where does the `productList` come from? Is it a data set that's asynchronously fetched in the parent, then passed down to the child as a prop? If so, it won't be there on initial render (i.e. when that effect runs on mount)

Comment: try to add log into the useEffect to see it really run or your getQuantityByID has issue 

useEffect(() => {
   console.log('Log sth here')
    getQuantityByID();
  }, []);

Comment: Can you please also share the parent component code if possible

Comment: Hi @Ceroy, the code is updated

Comment: Hi @taile , i have tried but still nothing get logged

Comment: the problem in getQuantityByID method. You filter but did not get or return the result
E.g: 
 const result = getQuantityByID = (Id) => {
    const result = productList.filter((item) => {

Comment: Hey @taile, i think you get misunderstood, getQuantityByID method actually used for passing to child component for using, not calling at parent because there is no "Id" parameter for passing to medthod